# Load testing Tapestry app mainly using javascript with JMeter

Tags: java, javascript, jmeter, load-testing, tapestry

I have a Tapestry application, which I want to load test using JMeter.

The problem is Tapestry app gives a response which is mainly javascript, no html to parse.

To be able to verify the response, I need to evaluate javascrpt.

Does anybody has any experience or pointers on how to do this ?

Comment: When you say 'To be able to verify the response, I need to evaluate javascrpt.', do you mean you want to run this javascript or that you just want to verify that some text is present in the response body? Or, is it that you need to execute some 'client-side' javascript in order to be able to send subsequent requests correctly? The latter is possible using BeanShell but it is not 'verification'.

Comment: You should look into using Geb and Selenium for testing if you need the application to actually execute. These fire up a real browser, rather than just send requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to search for specific expected values in the response you could use a post processor like the Regular Expression matcher.

See example here: http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

As Howard M. Lewis Ship has mentioned, you are probably best to use [Geb](http://www.gebish.org) for this. Geb is a layer of jQuery like groovy syntax that sits on top of [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org).

Normal usage is to have Geb/Selenium fire up a real browser (chrome/firefox/IE) to run the tests. There's also a java only / headless option to use a [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) which is much faster than firing up a browser. Note that the DOM / javascript provided by HtmlUnit runs on [rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) and may have it's own quirks that make it differ from a real browser(s).